# C++ translate phone keypad number into alphabet

Tags: c++

Simply,this program requires user to input a sequence of non-empty number e.g. 44477610223332145 at most 17 digits and output them into alphabet sentence.The translations is as follows:
2 is 'A',22 is 'B',222 is 'C',3 is 'D' etc
Remained that 0 represents a space and 1 is a pause for example 441444 to split 44 and 444.
Now my code encounters a run-time error, since I'm really new to c++ I dun know what's going on here. Please help to check. Thanks!

Thank you for the comments pointing out that I haven't included the error message, it says "vector subscript out of range".

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string n;
    vector<string> o;
    int i, x(0);
    map<string, char>character;

    {
        character["2"] = 'A';
        character["22"] = 'B';
        character["222"] = 'C';
        character["3"] = 'D';
        character["33"] = 'E';
        character["333"] = 'F';
        character["4"] = 'G';
        character["44"] = 'H';
        character["444"] = 'I';
        character["5"] = 'J';
        character["55"] = 'K';
        character["555"] = 'L';
        character["6"] = 'M';
        character["66"] = 'N';
        character["666"] = 'O';
        character["7"] = 'P';
        character["77"] = 'Q';
        character["777"] = 'R';
        character["7777"] = 'S';
        character["8"] = 'T';
        character["88"] = 'U';
        character["888"] = 'V';
        character["9"] = 'W';
        character["99"] = 'X';
        character["999"] = 'Y';
        character["9999"] = 'Z';
        character["0"] = ' ';
    }

    cout << "Please enter the message: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        if(n.at(i) == n.at(i + 1))
            o[x] = n.at(i) + n.at(i + 1);
        else
            x++;

        o[x] = n.at(i);
    }

    for(x = 0; x < o.size(); x++)
        cout << "Output message: " << character[o[x]] << endl;

    cout << "Count: " << o.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to check the correctness of the algorithm: what should the output of '25554440222222' be?

Comment: what is the exact error-message?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `if(n.at(i) == n.at(i + 1))` for the 17th element, because there's no element after that and `n.at(17)` will throw `std::out_of_range`.

Try this using [short-circuit-evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
if(i < 16 && n.at(i) == n.at(i + 1))
```

and the `n.at(i) == n.at(i + 1)` won't be evaluated for `i == 16`.

Moreover,

> program requires user to input a sequence of non-empty number e.g. 44477610223332145 **at most 17 digits**

but your loop is made to iterate 17 times even if `n` is shorter.

Comment: Thank you! but still can't run. It says "vector subscript out of range"

Comment: Your vector is empty and you try to access `o[x]`. You should use `push_back`.

Comment: Now it says "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0

Comment: Now I fixed all and everything is fine but want to ask how could I use 1 as pause function without display it as a space? I set 1 in the <map>as null character and it will display a space how could I remove it?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know what you're asking. You can ask a new question about that specific problem, but make sure it's clear and not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method

void decode(char *arr)
{
char keypad[][5] = {"0 ", "1", "ABC2", "DEF3", "GHI4", "JKL5", "MNO6", "PQRS7", "TUV8", "WXYZ9", "*", "#"};
char ch, *str;
size_t size = 1;
int i, j = 0;

```
str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

for(i = 0; i < strlen(arr); i++)
{
    switch(arr[i])
    {
    case '0':
        ch = keypad[0][1];
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[0][0];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '1':
        ch = keypad[1][0];
        i++;
        break;
    case '2':
        ch = keypad[2][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[2][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[2][2];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[2][3];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '3':
        ch = keypad[3][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[3][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[3][2];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[3][3];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '4':
        ch = keypad[4][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[4][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[4][2];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[4][3];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '5':
        ch = keypad[5][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[5][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[5][2];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[5][3];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '6':
        ch = keypad[6][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[6][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[6][2];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[6][3];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '7':
        ch = keypad[7][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[7][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[7][2];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[7][3];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[7][4];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '8':
        ch = keypad[8][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[8][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[8][2];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[8][3];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '9':
        ch = keypad[9][0];
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[9][1];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[9][2];
            i++;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[9][3];
            i++;
        }
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
            ch = keypad[9][4];
            i++;
        }
        break;
    case '.':

        continue;
    }

    *(str + j) = ch;
    str = (char*)realloc(str,size * sizeof(char));
    j++;
}

str[j] = '\0';

printf("%s",str);

free(str);
```

}